# Fade in/out when switching workspaces (using picom compositor)

Tags: i3, dwm, picom

Upon enabling fade with the `picom`  compositor, opening and closing windows will fade in and out.

I would like to see the same effect upon switching workspaces.

This works with `i3wm`, but not with the suckless `dwm`.

Comment: relevant thread: https://old.reddit.com/r/suckless/comments/snfuf3/can_you_enable_picom_fade_effect_for_switching/

Answer (score 1):

There is patch which you can try to get fading effect on dwm [windowmap](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/windowmap/)